# alignment issue with justify content - reactjs app

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need the options 1,2,3,4 to be aligned in a straight line. 
options 3 and 4 are centred. it should be aligned with 1 and 2.
how do I change this?

My css code is as below: result-box is the container. results-header is the "Poll results" and the options are in "results". I have used justify-content "stretch" but it doesn't work.

```
.result-box {
  background-color:#E8E8E8;
}

.results-header {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans';
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.results {
  color:#00B2EE;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: stretch;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans';
  margin: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a working code example or at least minimal HTML+css required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I would advise with  no html given look at this flex-box web page https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/ you have all ins and outs of flex-box and with trial an error you will succeed however I am having a feeling that ```flex-direction:column``` might solve problem but can't say much cause I no html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the `display: flex` propyerty for align-items and justify-content to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` with `.result` class.
Here try this one [w3schools-css-align](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp)

Comment: use this link to find how to align center https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: I can fix it for you if you attach the code somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the four items correctly aligned to the left.

```css
.results {
  text-align: center;
}

.results-title {
  margin: 0
}

.results-content {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="results">
  <h3 class="results-title">Poll results:</h1>
  <ol class="results-content">
    <li>Node.js</li>
    <li>Java</li>
    <li>Python</li>
    <li>C#</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```